# How to use public method removeTab(TabLayout.Tab tab)?

Tags: android

Checking [https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html][1] I created my tabs

```
tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1 Item").setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_email).setTag("tt"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 2 Item").setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_btn_speak_now));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 3 Item").setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_lock_idle_low_battery));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 4 Item").setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));
```

but then when I try to remove the tab I am getting error. My simple question is how can I use the method **removeTab(TabLayout.Tab tab)** ?

Comment: what kind of error do you have?

Comment: No error because I dont know how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for example:

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        TabLayout.Tab tab1 = tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1 Item").setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_email).setTag("tt");
        tabLayout.addTab(tab1);
        TabLayout.Tab tab2 = tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 2 Item").setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_btn_speak_now);
        tabLayout.addTab(tab2);
        tabLayout.removeTab(tab1); // remove first tab
```

Answer (score 1):

Create your tab outside the function and then add and remove them as you wish.

Something like :

TabLayout t = new TabLayout();
t.setText("test");

...

add(t);

remove(t);